# Log file not accessible

Tags: python

I'm hoping someone can help with this annoying error.  I have a log file that writes out a bunch of messages from different functions.  That works fine.  But, if there's an uncaught error, I'm trying to rename the file.  That's throwing an error:

```
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process:
```

I threw in a breakpoint and confirmed that the file is open at that point, but I don't know why.  I'm closing the file before I try to move it.  I did a search and saw a post that with is preferable to use with a file, so I switched.  It still isn't closing.  Any ideas?

```
log_path = 'C:/myfolderpath/'
log_name = 'filename.txt'

result = message.find('Error')
with open(log_path + log_name, 'a') as status:
    status.write(str(datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")) + ': ' + message + '\n')
status.closed
if result != -1:
    old_file = os.path.join(log_path, log_name)
    new_file = os.path.join(log_path, 'Error' + log_name)
    os.rename(old_file, new_file)
```

Comment: What is `status.closed` supposed to be doing?

Comment: @Jan - from the example I found using the with statement, that's closing the file.  From here: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects

Comment: No, `with` does that automatically.

Comment: If it does, then why am I still getting the error?  It's not closing

Comment: The error says the file is being used by another process, so it may not be your program at all.  Are you running the script in multiple processes?  Do you have the file open in a text editor?  (Coincidentally, I just had a problem like this yesterday where I couldn't write a CSV file because I had it open in Excel.)  You could also try rebooting--some long-departed process's close may not have worked.

Comment: @DennisSparrow - Once the program is done running, I can change the name with no problem, so it's not being used anywhere else.  I do have it set up to do multi-processing, but each process creates it's own file to update (by design), so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: OK, I think the problem is somewhere outside of the posted code, but I don't have any other ideas.

Comment: @DennisSparrow THANK YOU!  Ugh - it was because when I created the file initially, it was never closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to complete the posting, the solution, as @DennisSparrow said, was in a different part of the code.  As soon as that was suggested, it hit me.

I create the file when the code starts - to trap and log any messages or errors.  BUT, I never closed it after it was created!

What I was trying to do was use a global variable for the log file since it was used in multiple places, but when I made the function to write to it, I must've forgot and actually used a different variable to open the same file - opening it twice.  The reason the close statement didn't work is because it was only closing one instance, the create was still open.

Once I closed the initial create, it worked perfectly.

Ah - newbie errors :)